# what should be in the git description file?

Tags: git

After initialising a new local repo there is a `description` file present.

What is it used for and how should I format it? Or is it simply a local helper file.

This thread [Accessing git's `description' file](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/savannah-hackers/2009-03/msg00051.html) suggests one style, but no man page or other reference to why it should be the way it is.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`description` file is only used by the GitWeb program ( to display the description of the repo on the GitWeb page)

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain

Otherwise, how you use it is left to you and I don't see a point in a "style" for it.

Comment: It seems to be in section 5.5 onwards in the current pdf, but it's all useful.

Comment: Hence, it should be told: that file is indeed generally not filled in for a local clone. You typically use it in a bare repository for the _blessed_ repository where the Git Web GUI is reading repositories informations from (say indeed GitWeb, and the likes).

Comment: GitBlit also seems to use it.

Answer (score 53):

The `description` file can also be read by hook scripts or other scripts pertaining to the repository. For example, one popular hook script, [post-receive-email](https://github.com/stephenh/git-central/blob/master/server/post-receive-email), sends an email to all members when a commit is made to the repository, and uses the contents of the `description` file as the name of the repository in the email subject.

Comment: For completness, only the first line is used by the hook. Oh yes, and I have not found if the rest of the file is actually displayed anywhere... :-|

Comment: Another tool which uses this file is git2html, which is useful on static sites. I think that falls under your "scripts pertaining to the repository" umbrella :)

Answer (score 6):

**description** is just a text file that is shown as project description in web frontend.

Just write there something that explains what the repository is about.

Answer (score 2):

The content of this file is also used by gitolite with the "desc -ld" command.

you can modify this file, but it doesn't seem to me that it's taken into account to be commited.

Comment: To set or modify the description on a gitolite server, use ssh:
`ssh git@host desc <repo> <description string>`